# Ubuntu 16.04 init scripts output

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, init.d

I have some older init.d script, I used this commands for status and debug output from `/lib/lsb/init-functions`. But after upgrade to 16.04 no output is written and echo also does not work.

```
log_action_msg
log_warning_msg
log_daemon_msg
log_failure_msg
log_end_msg $?
```

Is it possible use this (or others) commands for output to console/terminal?

I tried change `DefaultStandardOutput` in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` to journal+console but it doesn't help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I solved installing `systemd`

```
sudo apt-get install systemd
```